# Remove User Defined Item from List

Tags: list, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I wanted to remove the Data from my `List` during `onTap` but I am unable to do so.

This is the code:

```
  Widget buildUser(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];
        final style = _selectedBusStop.contains(ListClass(user.data['BusstopName'], user.data['location'].latitude.toString(), user.data['location'].longitude.toString()))
        ? TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ): TextStyle(fontSize: 18);
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                user.data['image']
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(user.data['BusstopName'], style: style),
          subtitle: Text('Operating Hour: ' + user.data['OperatingHour'], style: style),
          trailing:
          _selectedBusStop.contains((ListClass(user.data['BusstopName'], user.data['location'].latitude.toString(), user.data['location'].longitude.toString()))) ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.blueAccent, size: 26) : null,
          onTap: (){
            if(_selectedBusStop.contains(ListClass(user.data['BusstopName'], user.data['location'].latitude.toString(), user.data['location'].longitude.toString()))){
              setState(() {
                _selectedBusStop.removeWhere((val) => val == ListClass(user.data['BusstopName'], user.data['location'].latitude.toString(), user.data['location'].longitude.toString()));
                print (_selectedBusStop);
              });
            }
          },
          onLongPress: (){
              setState(() {
                _selectedBusStop.add(ListClass(user.data['BusstopName'], user.data['location'].latitude.toString(), user.data['location'].longitude.toString()));
                print(_selectedBusStop);
              });
          }
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This is the `Class`:

```
class ListClass{
  String Bname;
  String Blat;
  String Blng;

  ListClass(this.Bname, this.Blat, this.Blng);

  @override
  String toString(){
    return '{${this.Bname}, ${this.Blat}, ${this.Blng}}';
  }
}
```

Any idea where went wrong? Thank you in advance.

**Update**
`List _selectedBusStop = [];`

`_selectedBusStop` is empty `List` and upon `LongPress` it will add data into the `List` and upon `onPress` it will remove the data if the data already exist in the `List`.

Comment: What is _selectedBusStop and where it is initialised and What I can see is in itemCount and builder you are using snapshot.data.documents but you are removing it from _selectedBusStop, Please share what is _selectedBusStop

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@randomstudent the issue is the instance, when you comaparing two values with different instance but even value is same, it returns false,

for example to understand simply.

```
void main() {
  final a = IntTestWrapper(3);
  final b = IntTestWrapper(3);
  print(a==b);
}

class IntTestWrapper {
  IntTestWrapper(this.a);
  final int a;
}
```

Output: false

If you want to compare, compare using equatable

if you change like this

```
class IntTestWrapper extends Equatable {
  IntTestWrapper(this.a);
  final int a;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [a];
}
```

then for this

```
void main() {
  final a = IntTestWrapper(3);
  final b = IntTestWrapper(3);
  print(a==b);
}
```

Output will be true.

To print you can override toString

```
void main() {
  final a = IntTestWrapper(3);
  final b = IntTestWrapper(3);
  print(a);
}

class IntTestWrapper extends Equatable {
  IntTestWrapper(this.a);
  final int a;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [a];

  @override
  String toString() => 'The value of a is :$a';
}
```

Output: `The value of a is :3`

Comment: @randomstudent in your code at onTap, In your "IF" cond you are creating a new Instance of ListClass, that's error, Just extend ListClass with Equatable, That should solve your problem.

Comment: If it helps please mark it as answer, Thank you.

Comment: Yes yes im giving it a try. Will definitely mark as answer if it works. But really good example and explaination.

Comment: Glad it heps you, Thanks, Happy to help.

Comment: sir but when I print out the `_selectedBusStop` it only shows this `ListClass, ListClass, ListClass`. How can I print the value inside each of them?

Comment: You can override toString to do that, Lemme update my answer.

Comment: thankyou so so much. I am able to get it work. Thank you so much man.

Comment: Sir 1 last question. If I wanted to print only one of the data for Example of the List `[{testing, test}, {testing1, test1}, {testing2, test2}]`. If I wanted to print only the first one with the `ing` have can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236227/discussion-between-mohan-sai-manthri-and-randomstudent).